# Java: Making a linked list in a while loop

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to make an int (like 123) into a linked list. For example: 123 would result in a linked list of 3 -> 2 -> 1. My issue is that I am able to get each part of the number(like 3 or 2) but I can't seem to make the linked list.

Here is my while Loop:

```
        value = Integer.parseInt(l1StrRev) + Integer.parseInt(l2StrRev);
        result = new ListNode(value % 10);
        value = value / 10;
        while(value > 0) {
            int newVal = value % 10;
            result.next = new ListNode(newVal);
            result = result.next;
            value = value / 10;
        }
```

I am getting back a linked-list of just one node with the most recent value.

Comment: Are you trying to use your own implementation of a LinkedList or use the one provided by java?

Comment: I am given a class: ListNode with int val, ListNode node, and a constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are updating the "result" variable too. So when u return the "result" variable, its actually pointing to the last Node. I would suggest, before the while loop do a resultCopy = result. And then in the end return resultCopy. This way, resultCopy stores the head node of the list, and "result" acts as a temporary node as in ur code.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are missing and mixed up a couple of lines. In your loop it should be something like...

- Create a new node

  `Node node = new ListNode(newVal);`
- Set node.next to the result

  `node.next = result;`
- Your result then becomes the new node above

  `result = node;`